# SQL Server Reporting Services Returns Too Many Records

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have 3 really big tables in SQL Server 2012 all related by phone number.  When I create a report with the Visual Studio BI Reporting Wizard I receive the following error:

> "An error occurred during local report processing. An error has occurred during report processing. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

I assume the report is returning too many records if it runs. How can I stop the report from automatically running? Or other suggestions?

The query used in the report is below.

```
SELECT table1.customer_phone, table2.PhoneNumber, table3.ANI
FROM LMIRSessions INNER JOIN
                  table1 ON table2.PhoneNumber = table1.customer_phone INNER JOIN
                  table3 ON table2.PhoneNumber = table3.ANI
```

Comment: Do a select count(1) to get the number of records returned to give everyone an idea of what you mean by "big" tables.  That might help with the responses

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding one or more [parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to the SSRS report to limit the number of records returned:

- A parameter could narrow down `PhoneNumber` values considered - by exact or pattern matches.
- Maybe there are sensible parameters to narrow the report's results by date and/or time too (judging by the table name `LMIRSessions`, which I expect may have columns like `SessionStart` and `SessionEnd`).
- Lastly (also judging by the table name `LMIRSessions`), maybe there are potential parameters to narrow the report's results by session type(s) or outcome(s).

It might also make sense to consider [paging](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic490774-147-1.aspx) report results.  Even without domain-specific filtering parameters like I have suggested above, you can employ paging to limit the number of records returned (and related resources required).